# Calculating type of polymorphism haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to calculate types of following expressions:

- curry fst
- foldr const
- (foldr const) . (curry fst)

First I have:

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
fst :: (d, e) -> d 

{}                      |   (a,b)-> c = (d,e) -> d 
{}                      |   (a,b) = (d,e) , c = d
c -> d                  |   (a,b) = (d,e)
c -> d , a ->d          |   b = e
c -> d , a ->d, b -> e  |   {}
```

then replace the result in a -> b -> c and you get d -> e -> d

Now similar to this I do:

```
foldr :: (f -> g -> g) -> g -> [f] -> g
const :: h -> i -> h



{}                      |    (f -> g -> g) =  h -> i -> h 
{}                      |    f = h , g = i, g = h
f -> h                  |    g = i, g = h
f -> h, g -> i          |    i = h
f -> h, g -> i  i->h    |    {}
```

then replace the result in g -> [f] -> g and you get i -> [h] -> i

Next, i  have to do 
`(foldr const) . (curry fst)` but i am not sure if these results are correct. I tried anyway but got stuck. So:

```
(foldr const) :: i -> [h] -> i and (curry fst) :: d -> e -> d
(.) :: (j -> k) -> (l -> j) -> l -> k
```

then i start with:

`d = (j -> k) -> (l -> j) -> l -> k, e =  d -> e -> d`

```
e = (j -> k) -> (l -> j) -> l -> k -> e -> (j -> k) -> (l -> j) -> l -> k
```

but it feels wrong and i cannot continue... 
Are my first two results correct? 
If they are, how should i solve the last one?

Comment: You can check this with `:type` in ghci. Is the purpose of the exercise to work it out for yourself?

Comment: yes, I should do it myself to learn how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first result is correct.

The calculation for the second result is correct until you make the substitution in the last step. Easily missed. You had (using `=`, rather than `->`, as the latter constructs function types and thus might cause confusion)

```
f = h, g = i, i = h
```

so substituting in `g -> [f] -> g` gives

```
h -> [h] -> h
```

not `i -> [h] -> i`, because although `g = i`, it's also the case that `i = h`, so together, `g = h`. That is, you need *either* to normalise your substitution (applying each new solution to instantiate the old substitution as well as extend it, giving `f = h, g = h, i = h`), *or* to apply your substitution carefully one step at a time:

```
g -> [f] -> g
  -- f = h
g -> [h] -> g
  -- g = i
i -> [h] -> i
  -- i = h
h -> [h] -> h
```

Now, for the final step of the calculation, you have all the pieces, but you have missed the way `.` is an infix operator. Its first argument is `foldr const` which must have type `j -> k`. Its second argument is `curry fst` which must have type `l -> j`. The whole thing has type `l -> k`. So, the equations you must solve are

```
j -> k  =  h -> [h] -> h   -- from the first argument
l -> j  =  d -> e -> d     -- from the second argument
```

Now, `->` associates to the right, so the first gives

```
j = h
k = [h] -> h
```

and the second gives

```
l = d
j = e -> d
```

Combining the two gives

```
h = e -> d
```

so we end up with (normalised)

```
h = e -> d
j = e -> d
k = [e -> d] -> e -> d
l = d
```

and instantiating `l -> k` gives the type

```
d -> [e -> d] -> e -> d
```

The function takes a default `d`, then a list of functions, then an input `e`: if the list of functions is empty, you get the default as the result; if the list is nonempty, you get the result of applying the first function to the input.

Comment: Example: `((foldr const) . (curry fst)) 0 [ceiling, floor, round] 0.1`

Comment: Another example: `((foldr const) . (curry fst)) undefined [ceiling, undefined] 0.9`